# Boolean: Cut Plane with Cylinder

Tags: modifiers

I am just learning Blender and am doing a tutorial on Udemy by Darrin Lile. While doing lecture 63 he separates a face off of an object and is able to use a Boolean modifier to cut a hole in that object.

However, when I try and repeat the steps I run into an issue. The hole isn't created but an extra edge is.

My scale and rotation are 1 and all faces are Blue. I've been told that you cant use a Boolean to cut a plane. However, I also saw that in version 2.90 you could. I am using 2.92.

If anyone could provided any help that would be great!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: IDK what is going wrong here, because from what I can see, that is supposed to work. Typically, Boolean have failed on me because of incorrect normals. PS: What settings are on the modifier?

Comment: If it's a plane you want to cut through, and not an enclosed volume, consider using the Knife Project feature instead of a boolean. It never fails. It's a bit quirky to set up, though. For starters, your cylinder will have to have its caps removed, because Knife Project works by projecting the knife cuts, as if from a shadow that is cast on the surface. Meaning that keeping the caps on the cylinder would block the projection. It also works based on camera angle, so that must be set up to view the target object perpendicularly. Finally, both cutter and cut object must be selected in Edit Mode.

Comment: @R-800 Depending on what he wants to do, _Knife Project_ might not be a good alternative. The _Boolean Modifier_ is non-destructive, easy to setup (and also easy to change the cutting object) and works just fine with a plane.

Comment: If the Boolean works fine with a plane, then it would definitely be a preferable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Check your *Boolean Modifier* if the *Solver* option is set to *Exact*. Although this sounds to be better, the *Fast* option sometimes works better for these things. Of course it is possible to cut a plane with a cylinder ;) I don't know when these *Solver* options were implemented, but since then it's the default so it sometimes gives bad results.

[image: boolean modifier]